# Is there a way to make a date like "1980-1-12" a valid value for DATE type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to insert different dates into the table down below. [The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSzMC.png)

```
CREATE TABLE companies
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    rate INT,
    created_on DATE NOT NULL,
    CHECK(rate >= 0 AND rate <= 10),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

There are hundredths of different values, many of which are correct to the YYYY-MM-DD format and pass effortlessly. But there are also a handful of dates that have a format of YYYY-M-D or something similar. Is it possible to make a variable accept and correctly read both formats?
[Some of the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67gSD.png)

```
  INSERT INTO companies(id, name, rate, created_on) VALUES 
    (1, 'Gaylord', 6, '2005-7-19'),
    (2, 'Feil Group', 9, '2018-1-26'),
    (3, 'Halvorson LLC', 3, '1988-1-24'),
    (4, 'Grant-Howell', 9, '1995-6-14'),
    (5, 'Gislason', 2, '2007-6-20'),
    (6, 'Harvey', 5, '2000-10-20'),
    (7, 'Kutch Ltd', 6, '2008-9-15'),
    (8, 'Harvey', 9, '2003-6-6'),
    (9, 'Wolff Inc', 5, '1989-4-8'),
    (10, 'Hackett PLC', 1, '1996-6-20'),
    (11, 'Schmeler', 3, '2010-7-26'),
    (12, 'Trantow-Breitenberg', 2, '1989-3-0')
);
```

The error message reads the following:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '1989-3-0' for column 'created_on' at row 12
```

Comment: you should show what you tried with CHECK.

Comment: I tried CHECK for the length of the date, but I didn't realise at the time that it doesn't work like a CASE statement.

Comment: What date value do you want to store for `'1989-3-0'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All versions of mysql (at least back through 5.5 and likely earlier) will silently accept and correctly parse single digit month or year without error, even with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES enabled.  You do not need to do anything special when you do your inserts.

If you want to see single digit month and year, do that using `DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%Y-%c-%e')` when you select.  If you find yourself doing that a lot, you could add a generated column:

```
alter table companies
    add formatted_created_on varchar(10) as (date_format(created_on,'%Y-%c-%e'))
```

and select formatted_created_on instead.

Comment: Again, my bad for not clarifiyng, but is there a keyword to make that when creating the table, not when making a query? Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: Just use the `DATE` datatype when you create the table.

Comment: a keyword for the default date format to select?  no.  you should always just specify it when you select.

Comment: @Barmar I have attached an image that shows the DDL of the table. In that image it is visible that I use DATE, but it throws an error (1292: Incorrect date value). Here is the link to that image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSzMC.png

Comment: please show the entire error message.  please do edit your question and add text, not images or links to images.

Comment: @ysth The entire error message is: "Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '1989-3-0' for column 'created_on' at row 12". I will edit the question and get back to you.

Comment: right, that's an invalid date, not just a single digit day.  what do you want to happen with that?

Comment: @ysth Now I think I formated the post the right way, is there anything else that would be helpful to add?

Comment: you've got date data you want to store, but some of your input is not valid dates.  you need to decide what to do with that bad data (clean it up or just store null for some rows)

Comment: So, this is an exam problem and I can't change the values in the 'INSERT' statements. Those values need to be inserted, and I have no control over that. Is that an issue in the 'system' that provided those values, or am I the issue?

Comment: you can make your date allow null and, in the session doing the INSERT, change to interpret bad dates as null by doing `set session sql_mode=replace(@@SESSION.sql_mode,'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','');` first.  or you can enable an old misfeature where month or day parts are allowed to be zero by doing `set session sql_mode=replace(@@SESSION.sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','');`.  or you can just store the dates in a varchar field.  in a real world scenario, any of those is a much worse choice than just cleaning up your data to have valid dates.

Comment: seems like your instructor comes from the distant past, where mysql was not at all as strict about validating dates